# ADSL+ modem and Wi-Fi router recommendation for India

Tags: wifi, router

I'm kind of looking for a replacement and am really confused of the options available so I need suggestion from experts out there!

I've a Linksys WAG 200G ADSL model which had a 54Mbps wifi speed and a fair range.

Since there are a fair number wi-fi devices including 5 network cams, I'm looking for a good modem with nice range (to cover approx area of 750 Sq Ft) and equal or above wi-fi speeds of 300Mbps. I have a 10Mbps ADSL+ Intrenet connection from state owned BSNL India.

I'm looking for a combination of a good ADSL+ modem and Wi-Fi router. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations. What kind of walls do you have? What is your budget? Are you open to the possibility of having separate modems, access points or routers?

Comment: Thanks. I have conventional 14 inch brick walls and a lot of open area with 2 different building blocks. Initially I do have a netgear wi-fi router as well but I was kind of looking for a single device to handle both internet and network.

Comment: I'm looking for a mix of performance and cost effectiveness, Can spend up to INR 7000 to 10000 for a good device. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there's only 750 square feet and not 7500 square feet? That's a radius of less than 9 meters, which seems a bit small to fit 2 buildings into. For 2 buildings, I think I'd recommend multiple access points, connected by Ethernet. I'll have to get back to you later though.

Comment: Ok, yes may be I'm wrong about the area, what is the maximum range I can get from a single modem+wifi device? Just curious.

Comment: If there is a clear, unobstructed path, 30 meters should be no problem with any reasonable access point. Walls make things so much worse though. For the speeds you're looking at,  you'd probably need dual band routers, with the closer devices connected to the 5 GHz. Can your current modem cover most of your block? If so, I'd recommend using it, in *addition* to any other routers you purchase. It would improve any congestion too. MU-MIMO could also be something you should consider, though it is quite expensive, so it might not be worth it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41300/discussion-between-alpha3031-and-anupam).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [TPLINK AC1750 ARCHER D7](http://www.amazon.in/TPLINK-AC1750-ARCHER-D7-Router/dp/B00IU85YE6/), INR 8,529.00 and free shipping from Amazon.in. The [CNET.au review](http://www.cnet.com/au/products/tp-link-archer-d7-ac1750/2/) shows that it has a real throughput of more than 300 Mbps total. However, much of this bandwidth comes over the 5 GHz band, so you still might require your old router for extra range (run a Ethernet cable across)

It integrates a ADSL 2+ modem, as required, and should be able to cover most of your property.